# Copy updated row values using a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a config table I want to put a trigger on to synchronise column values after update.

```
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+
|type| key     |  value        | dateModified| 
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | MyAPItok|     as7373    | 2019-04-16  |   
|  2 | MyAPItok|     br7345    | 2019-04-12  |   
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+
```

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SyncAPITokens]
ON [dbo].[tbl_config]
AFTER UPDATE  
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE disp
    SET disp.value = i.[value],
        disp.dateModified = i.[dateModified]
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_config] disp
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.[type] = disp.[type] AND i.[key] = disp.[key] -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
    WHERE disp.[key] ='MyAPItok'
END
```

I have tried several variations but nothing seems to work. Whenever I update the value with key "MyAPItok" I want every row with the same key to be assigned the updated value and dateModified. Does anyone know why this does not work?

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE for the update

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SyncAPITokens]
ON [dbo].[tbl_config]
AFTER UPDATE  
AS 
BEGIN
    with q as 
    (
      select  disp.*, 
              i.value value_new,
              i.dateModified dateModified_new

      FROM [dbo].[tbl_config] disp
      INNER JOIN Inserted i 
        ON i.[type] = disp.[type] 
        AND i.[key] = disp.[key] -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
      WHERE disp.[key] = 'MyAPItok'
    )
    --select * from q
    update q set value = value_new, dateModified = dateModified_new;
END
```

And then you can toggle the comment to see a resultset from the trigger for debugging purposes.  You might discover that your trigger doesn't really do anything.